# finding strings in one list and based on what it says, replacing it with strings from another list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

basically I have a user enter a sentence

eg. "hello, how are you?"

and from a large list it replaces "are" with "am" and "you" with "I". to return:

"hello, how am i?"

problem is i have no idea how to do this.

so my list looks a bit like `reflections = [["I, you"],["are","am]] ---> etc.`

and so far i've got some code which collects raw input from the user and then calls this function to reply to it.

```
def reflects_users_string(reply):
    reply_list = reply.split()
    for _ in reply_list
       if ???? 
           ????
            ???? 
   else 
       print "i don't understand"
```

from what I understand (noob here) it turns the users input into a list and then compares each item in that list with items in the "reflections" list, then it replaces the identical string in one list with the string next to it eg. "are" with "am"

ive been playing with all sorts of ways to do this but just cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try learning to use list comprehensions, it's a powerful way to filter out lists in make iterations.

Let's try to solve your problems with list comprehensions:

```
#first we need to create mappings in a dict for your reflections
reflect = {
    'you': 'I',
    'are': 'am'
}

# After we read user input
user_input = 'hello, how are you ?'


#Now look how we can replace all words in user_input from reflect with one line
reflected = [word for word in [reflect.get(key, key) for key in user_input.split()]]

print ' '.join(reflected)
```

Let's analyse the list comprehension:

1. First we split user input into a list `user_input.split()`
2. Then we iter through the user input words `for key in
       user_input.split()`
3. For each word in user input words we query the reflect dict. Using
       `reflect.get(key, key)` is a way to query the `reflect` dict for key
       and if we can't find the key a default value of `key` is returned
       instead.
4. Finally, we wrap all this comprehension with `[word for word in [getting reflected words from user input and a default value of the same word if we can't find it's reflection]]`

And Voila !

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start so far. As for next step, make a big dict of all the mappings of words, look up each word in that dict, and replace it if it has a replacement.

Comment: so do you mean change my list to a dictionary so that each word has an assigned replacement word in my dictionary that i can just switch for or what?